# Indexing directories

Tags: shell

I have a rather silly question regarding the shell. I would like to `scp` the content of a large number of directories into some other large number of directories, both of which are indexed in the same manner.

In a nutshell, I would like to do something like:

`scp usr@silly:~/desktop/AP#/data/* ~/Desktop/A#`

where `#` refers to the same index.

Comment: Try doing `SCP` of `~/desktop/AP#` to destination and move contents of `data` to previous `A#` directories and delete `data` directories in destination.

Comment: If your indexes are known, you can make a cycle to iterate with different indexes. But that would be awful due to multiple ssh sessions.

Answer (score -1):

You can get inside the host and group all that files in a folder:

```sh
for file in $(ls ~/desktop/AP*); do 
    cp -r $file/data/* ~/desktop/my_tmp_dir/$file; 
done
```

and then do, from your host, an integral copy of that folder:

`scp usr@silly:~/desktop/my_tmp_dir/* ~/Desktop/`

Comment: [Don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)